# a property of a morphism of ordered groups

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, ordered-groups

An ordered group $(G,G^+)$ is an abelian group $G$ together with a subsemigroup $G^+$ containing the identity $0$, having these properties:

$G^+-G^+=G$.

$G^+\cap (-G^+)=\{0\}$.

We have for $x,y\in G$: $x\le y$ if $y-x\in G^+$.

A morphism $f:(G,G^+)\to (H,H^+)$ of ordered abelian groups is a group homomorphism $f:G\to H$ satisfying $f(G^+)\subseteq H^+$.

In my situation, $f$ is an injective morphism of ordered abelian groups (not sure if injectivity is important). Set $f(G)^+ :=f(G)\cap H^+$.

Is $f(G^+)= f(G)^+$ (at least, if $f$ is injective)?

Trivially, $f(G^+)\subseteq f(G)\cap H^+$. But what about $f(G)\cap H^+\subseteq f(G^+)$?

I came as far as this: Let $a,b\in f(G)^+$ with $a\le b$, let $x,y\in G$ with $f(x)=a\le f(y)=b$. Then $b-a=f(y-x)$. But does $b-a$ lift to an element in $G^+$, i.e. is  $y-x \in G^+$?

Comment: What's your definition of $f(G)^+$? Is it $f(G)^+=f(G)\cap H^+$?

Comment: Oh, good point, yes it is. The remaining question is, if $f(G)\cap H^+\subseteq f(G^+)$ holds

Comment: I just have modified my question

Answer (score 0):

If $-x \in G^+$, then $-f(x) = f(-x) \in H^+$, and therefore $f(x) \in -H^+$. So $f(-G^+) \subseteq -H^+$.

Comment: thanks. Sorry, I'm a beginner with university math. Is $f(-G^+)\subseteq -H^+$ equivalent to $f(G)\cap H^+\subseteq f(G^+)$?

Comment: I intentionally left the rest to you. For your own sake, you REALLY should figure that out yourself, recalling the relationships between $G, G^+, -G^+$ and between $H, H^+, -H^+$

Comment: ok, I will do that